# how to use anchor tags with $stateProvider to redirect to another page in angular js ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am having a login page with forgot password anchor tag , on the click of my forgot password link i should be redirected to my forgot password page i am not able to redirect it , i am using $stateProvider to route my pages accordingly , kindly help me to resolve the issue .

here is my login.html  page with forgot password link:

```
 <div class="input-element-row">
                <div class="forgot-pass"><a ui-sref="forgot">Forgot password?</a></div>
            </div>
```

here is my router.js that contains routing of pages :

```
angular.module("nk.login", [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate'
  ]).
    config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
      $stateProvider
        .state('app.login', {
          url: '/login',
          views: {
            "content": {
              templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/login.html',
              controller: 'loginController'
            }
          }
        })
          .state('app.forgotPassword', {
              url: '/forgot',
              views: {
                  "content": {
                      templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/forgotPassword.html',
                      controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
                  }
              }
          })
    }]);
```

here is my forgotpwd.html page:

```
<div class="inputs-container">
            <form name="forgotPassword" novalidate>
                <div class="input-element-row">
                    <div class="rgt-input-box fl"><span class="center-icon action-icon"></span><input type="text"
                    ng-model="Nuser.center_code" placeholder="Center Code" name="CenterCode" value=""
                          ng-pattern = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/" maxlength="5" required ng-disabled="isDisable"/></div>
                    <div class="cb">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-element-row">
                    <div class="rgt-input-box fl"><span class="user-icon action-icon"></span><input type="text"
                    placeholder="User ID"  ng-model="Nuser.login_id" name="UserID" value=""
                    ng-pattern = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/" maxlength="10" required ng-disabled="isDisable"/></div>
                    <div class="cb"></div>
                </div>




                <div class="input-element-row">
                    <button type="button" name="send"  ng-click="send(userLogin)">Send</button>

                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ui-sref` working with `state` not `url`.

So you have to pass state name instead of url.

i.e `ui-sref="app.forgotPassword"`

Change :

```
<div class="forgot-pass"><a ui-sref="forgot">Forgot password?</a></div>
```

To :

```
<div class="forgot-pass"><a ui-sref="app.forgotPassword">Forgot password?</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks it works for me , didnt knew i was committing such a stupid mistake . nyways thanks a lot